# jooq mysql select by <R extends Record> unique keys, with no regard to field name

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm writing a method which inserts or updates a record into mysql table, and updating only happens when the field "sample_time" is larger than this value of the current record in table. The following is how I want to do it now.

```
 public <R extends Record> void upsertRecord(Table<R> table, R record) {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    DSL.using(getConfiguration()).transaction(configuration -> {
        try (DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(configuration)) {

            R old = // select with unique keys of table


            // something like if (old.get("update_time) < record.get("update_time"))
                dslContext.insertInto(table).set(record).onDuplicateKeyUpdate().set(record).execute();
                conn.commit();
           // }   
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO
        } finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't know how to select by record's unique keys with no regard to the exact field name or field number. So my question is :

1. how could I implement 'select by record's unique keys with no regard to the exact field name or field number'
2. or else how could I use an conditional on duplicate update with condition in jooq

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You seem to be implementing "optimistic locking" on top of jOOQ. Are you aware of this feature? https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/optimistic-locking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a reference to the `PrimaryKey` meta information through [`Table.getPrimaryKey()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#getPrimaryKey--):

```
UniqueKey<R> key = table.getPrimaryKey();
if (key != null) {
    List<TableField<R, ?>> fields = key.getFields();

    // Now create your condition from these fields
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well with single primary key but seems not working with composite primary key... I've update my codes in the question.

Comment: @user3352035: May I suggest you revert that edit and ask a new question? Quite likely: 1) your new question isn't really related to your previous one 2) If you copy my answer into your question, this question (and my answer) will become much less useful for anyone who will visit this question in the future.

Comment: You're right, I've reverted the question. Thank you for the help! ：）

Comment: @user3352035: Perfect, thank you. I'll look out for your new question and answer there

Comment: Never mind, I've found my mistake, I used field(tf.getName()) in stead of  getValue(tf.getName()) by mistake, the correct select sql should be : selectQuery.addConditions(tf.eq(record.getValue(tf.getName())));

Comment: I wonder if my table has a composite unique key besides the primary key, how could I get all the unique keys?

Comment: @user3352035: [`Table.getKeys()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#getKeys--)